# Add "views" ordering to answer list again

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, user-profiles, views

There once was a *views* sort order for answers in a user's profile, but it apparently was removed. It is only available for questions.

> [image]
>
> [image]

While it might need to be made clear that it's not *answer* views, but question/topic views, it was useful for determining which of my answers get more traffic than others, and might profit most from improvement edits. In that respect, showing the views over the lifetime of the question instead of the answer (in case of late answers) would be better anyway.